# get fee price in between price range start price and endprice

Tags: mysql

I have a table which hold value  price range and fee something link that

```
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| start_price | end_price | fees_amount |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|         100 |      1000 |      5.0000 |
|        1001 |      2000 |     10.0000 |
|        2001 |      3000 |     15.0000 |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

If i input 1200 then i wont to get fees_amount `10.0000` because `1200` is between `1001-2000` slab ,

Please help me with mysql Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query using [`BETWEEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between):

```
SELECT fees_amount 
FROM table_name 
WHERE 1200 BETWEEN start_price AND end_price
```

Another solution would be the following query:

```
SELECT fees_amount 
FROM table_name 
WHERE 1200 >= start_price AND 1200 <= end_price
```